# Network storage is not mounted to the SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 10

Tags: linux, networking, network-share, mount, sles

command

```
mount XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:/store/ /mnt/test
```

Error

```
    mount server reported tcp not available, falling back to udp mount: RPC: 
Remote system error - Network is unreachable
```

The server has successfully received the IP address.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check your firewall  Yast -> Security and Users -> Firewall. Make sure NFS services is enabled.

Comment: I solved the problem. Files with the routes were broken.